# Is it suitable to write plain text in html without lable?

Tags: html

I just started to learn Frontend coding, and I get confused at this, which is something about html:
If we can write plain text without lable? I tried and it successed.By checking in browser I see it is called "text". What's the function of it? Why it's allowed in html? 
e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            text
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>hi</h3>
        plain text feild.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You Please explain it further more !!!

Comment: Yeah, I am just wondering if we can use direct text in html without tags like<p>, and I read other question answers explaining that it is related to html versions, so maybe that's the answer of it.